# Automatically write data from one sheet to other with the help of dropdown box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-gsuite

I have a drop down box with 3 options in my sheet 1 and I want to copy data from sheet 1 to the dedicated sheets in the same spreadsheet according to the option selected, how do I do that?

Comment: anything to refer will also do

Comment: Do you prefer an Apps Script solution or a Google Sheet functions solution? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). If you want to detect any changes in the dropdown and copy paste your original range to other sheet depening on the values of this dropdown, you want to use an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) simple trigger that will run your function everytime the value of a cell is changed (in your case the dropdown).

Then by just simply using the methods [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) along with [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) you can move your range from one Sheet to another as you pleased. The following piece of code includes self explanatory comments on the example range and dropdown shown below:

```js
function onEdit() {

  // Get sheet 1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // Get sheet 2 
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  // Get sheet 3 
  var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet3');

  // Get value of dropdown
  var value = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();

  // Get values of the range in Sheet 1 that we want to copy in other sheets
  var range = sheet.getRange('B1:C2').getValues();

// If dropdown value is A
  if(value=='A'){
    // Set the values of the range you want in sheet 2
    // Bare in mind that for this to work the range in the new sheet must
    // be equal size in rows and columns as from the range we are getting in
    // the original sheet
    sheet2.getRange('B1:C2').setValues(range);
  // If it is B (and you could go on with as many as you want)
  }else if(value=='B'){
    sheet3.getRange('B1:C2').setValues(range);
  }else{

  }
}
```

[image]